# Parameter "e" in function

Tags: javascript

```
window.onkeyup = keyup;

var inputTextValue;

function keyup(e) {
  inputTextValue = e;
  $('#searchValue').text("https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + inputTextValue);

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    window.location = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + inputTextValue;
  }
}
```

1. I dont understand this code. Does "window.onkeyup = keyup" mean that window.onkeyup will copy the value of the variable keyup?
2. What does the parameter e do ? I don't see code that call the function and pass argument to that e parameter

Comment: `window.onkeyup = keyup` is assigning the `keyup` function to be the event handler for the `keyup` event. And `e` is the variable name to which the `Event` object is being assigned when the function is called.

Comment: Think of it like `window.onkeyup = function (e) { ... }`

Comment: this one is the `event` ( shortname is `e`)

Comment: so the argument is passed automatically thus the parameter is optional?

Answer (score 2):

`window.onkeyup = keyup;` assigns the keyup function to the onkeyup property of the window. The function is then used as the event handler whenever a keyup event occurs on the window (or bubbles up to it).

> The keyup event fires when the user releases a key that was previously pressed.

`e` is the event, which is, in this case, a `KeyboardEvent`.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup), for `target.onkeyup = functionRef`:

> functionRef is a function name or a function expression. The function receives a KeyboardEvent object as its sole argument.

Answer (score 1):

answer:

1. when keyboard key will release then the `keyup` function will be called.
2. `e` is the even object mainly `e` contain the keyboard related value,s example `e.keyCode` equal  `13` for enter key.

so `if (e.keyCode == 13)` means when enter key will press and release then that block will be execute.